# Issue with cx-freeze application: It is running for only 1 second

Tags: python, export, pygame, cx-freeze

I made a game in python, and then exported it with [cx-freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/). For some reason, when I try to double-click on the application it opens a command line for about a second and then closes. However, when I run it myself with just the python IDLE it works fine. What am I missing?

If it helps: I have graphic files in a separate folder called data and I'm using the normal python modules + [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you application is a GUI, you should freeze it with the "Win32GUI" base, so it doesn't open a command line. Have a look at [an example in the docs](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cxfreeze_distutils.html).

I don't know why it's closing again - maybe it's failed to include something it needs. When you freeze it with the GUI base, any error messages should appear in a message box, which might help you work out what the problem is.